# Angular Firestore database I always got an error

Tags: angular, cloud, angularfire

I always got the following error:

src_app_ddd_module_ts.js:2 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).
Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).

In the app.module.ts

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp, getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

In the

```
imports: [

    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore(getApp()))

...
]
```

In the component:
imports:

```
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
import { getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
```

global variable

```
db = getFirestore(getApp());
```

retrieve data:

const docRef = doc(this.db, "docdata", "XdQH3683YpCeGhQ6MqO0");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
let data = docSnap.data();
console.log(data);

What I missed?
What is the best way to retrieve the data?
Only one field in the Firestore Database.

The db is a public database not need auth I created just for testing purposes.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should really be creating a firebase.service or something to handle these requests rather than doing them directly in a component. However, you should be able to get this working by doing the following.

app.module.ts

```js
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
...

  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    ...
  ]
```

component (should be in a service instead)

```js
import {Firestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

constructor(
    private firestore: Firestore
  ) {
  getDoc(doc(this.firestore, 'docdata/XdQH3683YpCeGhQ6MqO0')).then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.data())
  });
}
```

and PLEASE remove the global variable. That is very rarely the answer and can open your code up to all kinds of other issues.

Comment: I don't think the location, (is it in service or other place) will affect the result, but I try that.

Comment: Correct, the location won't affect the code but generally, you want operations like these contained within a service and no inside of a component.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the working solution is:

1. I moved the imports from the app.module.ts to that module where exactly I using it
2. In the module main component I did the following

The imports:

```
  import { Firestore, collectionData, collection, DocumentData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

A class variables:

```
myDocData$: Observable<DocumentData[]>;
firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);
```

The code:

```
  const itemCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'mydocdata');
  this.myDocData$ = collectionData(itemCollection);
  this.myDocData$.subscribe(data =>{
    ...
  });
```

Thease are based on the [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire).

Comment: Glad to see you got it working. You should still be moving these items into a service however as it reduces the overall complexity of your application as well as reducing the amount of excess boilerplate. You could have a generalized method `getCollection(name)` that returns a collection or the same for collectionData. Once you get further into using Firebase, boilerplate code tends to swell very quickly unless properly setup.